# Firefox fails to launch on 2014 computer running Big Sur

Tags: homebrew, big-sur, firefox

I reinstalled my Mac computer from 2014 with Big Sur. I installed Firefox with

```
brew install --cask Firefox
```

and it worked for a few days, then it stopped working. I reinstall with:

```
brew remove --cask Firefox
brew install --cask Firefox
```

When I launch it, the OS does not even ask for a verification such as "This program was downloaded from the internet, are you sure you want to open it?". Instead, I get this message in the Terminal:

```
$ open -a Firefox
The application /Applications/Firefox.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10673 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=3878, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
```

Is Firefox still compatible with my environment?

### update

Today I restarted the computer and Firefox works. Now it's Opera that is not working:

```
$ open -a Opera
The application /Applications/Opera.app cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10673 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=3878, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
```

So the problem is not from the browser, but from my system. And yet, the reason I am reinstalling the browsers is because I did a fresh new install of Big Sur, during which I wiped out the hard drive with Disk Utility.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't just download Firefox from firefox.com, drag it to the /Applications folder and launch it that way? You can *still* launch it via terminal if you like...

Comment: I use brew and command-line because it's faster and can go into a script. I tried installing Opera per the comments, with a download from opera.com , and Opera now works as well. Can you write an answer?

Comment: Write an answer? you rejected my comment, I don't understand.

Comment: @SteveChambers Downloading the image and installing it manually fixed the problem, so that is a solution useful for others and I'll accept it. Installing it with brew and keeping it up to date is a separate problem, and I'll ask about it in a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing it the old fashioned way  ;-)

Go to firefox.com and download the latest version. Once downloaded open the dmg file and drag it to /Applications.

If you need to launch it via a shell you can point your command to the firefox executable inside the firefox app package.